# How to get MVC web grid dropdown column value using javascript or from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, webgrid

We have a dropdown list column in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 WebGrid. User will select a item from that list for each row.
When i click on submit I need to capture the selected value for each row.
Can anyone please give me a sample code for doing this from controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can make a column with DropDownList control using a html helper:

```
grid.Column("List", header: "List", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownList("selection", someItems)</text>)
```

Then put the whole grid in a "form" statement, which refers to "Save" action in your controller, and create that "Save" action method like this:

```
public ActionResult Save(string[] selection) {
    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don'y you give telerik.mvc grid a try. It's super smooth and handles such scenarios pretty well. Moreover the effort is pretty less in setting it up.

You can download it as a nuget package.

Examples are here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid

Comment: We should not use thirdparty controls :(

Comment: Just keep in mind that it's GPL licensed so not suitable for everyone (commercial license is available)

Comment: is there any other option to achieve this? please help me